# Does LaTeX define a semantic equivalent of \textbf ?

Tags: bold, emphasis, semantics

In HTML, there's the distinction between `<em>` as semantic markup and `<i>` as its pure-formatting equivalent.  LaTeX has the same distinction: `\emph` is semantic markup, rendered using `\textit`.

HTML also includes an analogous distinction between `<strong>` and `<b>`.  Does LaTeX define a semantic command (e.g. `\strong{...}`, but that doesn't exist) that gets rendered using `\textbf`?

EDIT: on very similar lines, does LaTeX define a semantic command like `\quote{...}` that will render using quotation marks (of some preferred type)?  (HTML has `<q>`.)

Comment: For the quote macro see the `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can define your own `\strong` command which switches between strong and normal text like `\emph` does with italic:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strong}[1]{\@strong{#1}}
\newcommand{\@@strong}[1]{\textbf{\let\@strong\@@@strong#1}}
\newcommand{\@@@strong}[1]{\textnormal{\let\@strong\@@strong#1}}
\let\@strong\@@strong
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text \strong{strong text \strong{strong2 \strong{st-\strong{st}-st}  yyy } xxxx} after

\end{document}
```

[image: Result1]

---

Or you can define different levels of "strong" using a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{stronglevel}
\setcounter{stronglevel}{1}
\newcommand{\strong}[1]{%
    \csname strong\roman{stronglevel}\endcsname{{%
        \advance\value{stronglevel} by 1\relax
        #1%
    }}%
}
\newcommand{\strongi}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\strongii}[1]{{\blendcolors*{!50!red}\color{.}#1}}
\newcommand{\strongiii}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\strongiv}[1]{{\blendcolors*{!50!red}\color{.}#1}}

\begin{document}

Text \strong{strong text \strong{strong2 \strong{st-\strong{st}-st}  yyy } xxxx} after \strong{next}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result2]

Comment: Now you're just showing off... :-)

Comment: @Matthew: Originally I had `\strongiv` which included `\blink` and a `\strongv` which used `\smellbad`. :-) Both require of course ePaper.

Answer (score 14):

`\emph` doesn't render always as `\textit`. It switches between upright and italic as you can see if you nest `\emph`commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc \emph{some text \emph{emph} some text}
\end{document}
```

And there is no similar command which switches between bold and normal, but it would be easy to define. Simply copy the definition of `\em` and `\emph` from latex.ltx.

Comment: How would that definition work for strong? What would be the conditional you would check? Something like `\iftextisbold`? `\em` checks for positive `\fontdimen1` What would be the analogue for bold?

Comment: I would check if `\f@series` is equal to `\bfdefault`.

Comment: Should strong within strong be normal? Or maybe it should be _more strong!!!_: coloured text, or rendered in a caligraphic font or both. Or increased text size... The possibilities are endless...

Comment: strong is not semantic in the same way that emph is: there is no typographical convention on using boldface in the way that there is for using italics. So the lack of a `\strong` command isn't surprising.

Comment: A good point WRT to switching in nesting.  It turns out that standard HTML rendering doesn't do any switching in `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<i>` or `<em>`.

Answer (score 13):

The answer to your first question is "no, but it's easy to do it". Just add `\let\strong\textbf` to your preamble.

The second question's answer is "no, but there's a package that does it in a very clever way". The [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) defines `\enquote` which does what you want.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the absence of `\strong` (or the decision to use italic font for `\emph`) is a conscious one to discourage writers from using bold font in running text. The reason for this is that LaTeX tries to set paragraphs in such a way to obtain an equal level of 'grey', which looks better, and is easier on the eyes. For the same reason, underlining and letterspacing are not implemented by default, since they too affect text greyness.

Note that this of course raises a somewhat philosophical point: should a typesetting engine 'protect' its users from making a (typographically speaking) bad decision, or should they allow the user to do most anything they would want, up to the typographical equivalent of shooting oneself in the foot? I have the feeling that LaTeX mostly adheres to the philosophy of protecting the user---just look at how difficult it is (by default) to change all the typographical settings.

Of course this is essentially a non-answer ;) but I still wanted to make the point.

Comment: Another thing LaTeX does in this vein is to make changing font face a little tricky: good typography practice suggests using the same font throughout.

Comment: @Seamus: it would be best if it was easy to set any font at the start of the document, and then hard to change. Right now, my impression is that it is hard to do anything else than the standard fonts :).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Changing fonts is made significantly easier with the [fontspec](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) package, which works well with XeTeX and LuaTeX, at the very least. Adding arbitrary TTF or OTF fonts becomes a one-liner per font with fontspec.

Answer (score 4):

As Seamus and Ulrike have pointed out, the LaTeX core does not define `\strong` or another semantic command that uses `\textbf`. The `beamer` class, however, does something that comes close: In addition to `\emph`, it defines `\alert` which displays its argument in red color.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `semantic-markup` package! It defines `\strong`, `\quoted`, `\term`, and other commands of this type.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Seamus’ answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14668): LaTeX by itself does not define such semantic commands, but

- The `fontspec` package defines `\strong`, which is essentially the same as `\textbf`:

  ```
  \documentclass{scrartcl}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \begin{document}
     Using \strong{strong \strong{in fontspec}}
  \end{document}
  ```
- The `csquotes` package defines `\enquote`, which behaves similarly to `<q>` in HTML.